# CSS trying too center a list and a header

Tags: html, css

Im having such a weird offset when i try too center a h1 and a horizontal align list ...

[image]

The list has a slightly offset too the right, but why?
How can i center both perfectly?

```css
*   {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: black;
}

header h1  {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 5.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial;
    letter-spacing: 11px;
    color: white;
}

nav {
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: small;
    text-align: center;
    word-spacing: 15px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

li  {
    display: inline;
}

li a    {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
    <body>
    <header>
        <h1>Header</h1>
    </header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Leben</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Karriere</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Alben</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Filme</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Auszeichnungen</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</body>
```

Thanks for the help, very appreciate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the margin/padding from the `ul`:

```
nav ul {
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0;
}
```

```css
*   {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: black;
}

header h1  {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 5.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial;
    letter-spacing: 11px;
    color: white;
}

nav {
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: small;
    text-align: center;
    word-spacing: 15px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
}

li  {
    display: inline;
}

li a    {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Header</h1>
    </header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Leben</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Karriere</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Alben</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Filme</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Auszeichnungen</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</body>
```

Comment: Haha well... i literally struggled like 2 hours on that, tanks dude :D